# Error in c# Script utube example

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been following a utube example and have become stuck, I am trying to make a block disappear when player head buts block I have been given code but it is not working.  I am getting the following error

> Assets/Scripts/BlockDestroy.cs(15,4): error CS1622: Cannot return a value from iterators. Use the yield return statement to return a value, or yield break to end the iteration

here is my code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BlockDestroy : MonoBehaviour {

    public float xPos; 
    public float yPos; 
    public float zPos; 
    float waiting = 0.02F; 

    IEnumerator OnTriggerEnter(Collider col) { 
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player") { 
            this.transform.position = new Vector3(xPos, yPos + 0.1F, zPos); 
            return new WaitForSeconds(waiting); 
            this.transform.position = new Vector3(xPos, yPos + 0.2F, zPos); 

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(waiting); 
            transform.GetComponent<Collider>().isTrigger = false; 
            this.transform.position = new Vector3(xPos, yPos + 0.3F, zPos + 0.5F); 

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(waiting); 
            this.transform.position = new Vector3(xPos, yPos + 0.4F, zPos + 1.0F); 

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(waiting); 
            this.transform.position = new Vector3(xPos, yPos - 0.1F, zPos + 1.5F); 

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(waiting); 
            this.transform.position = new Vector3(xPos, yPos - 0.6F, zPos + 2.0F); 

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(waiting); 
            this.transform.position = new Vector3(xPos, yPos - 1.6F, zPos + 2.0F); 

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(waiting); 
            this.transform.position = new Vector3(xPos, yPos - 2.6F, zPos + 2.0F); 

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(waiting); 
            this.transform.position = new Vector3(xPos, yPos - 4.0F, zPos + 2.0F); 

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.25F); 
            transform.GetComponent<Collider>().isTrigger = true; 
            Destroy(gameObject); 

        } 
    } // Use this for initialization 

    void Start() {
        xPos = transform.position.x;
        yPos = transform.position.y;
        zPos = transform.position.z;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `yield` keyword at the following line:

```
if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player") { 
    this.transform.position = new Vector3(xPos, yPos + 0.1F, zPos); 
    //return new WaitForSeconds(waiting); // ← HERE
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(waiting); // CORRECT
    this.transform.position = new Vector3(xPos, yPos + 0.2F, zPos);
```

Comment: thank you been looking that this code for for about 1/2 an hour so obvious now thank you.